# How can I switch between sky boxes using a key?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SkyBox : UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material[] skyboxes;
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        RenderSettings.skybox = skyboxes[0];
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            if (RenderSettings.skybox != null && RenderSettings.skybox == skyboxes[1])
            {
                RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat("_Rotation", Time.time * moveSpeed);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first problem is how to make that it will switch between skyboxes 0 and 1 in the Update ?

Second problem is how to use the default skybox as the skyboxes at index 0 ?
I can't find the default skybox in the Assets :

[image: No default skybox]

Another problem I found now. My skybox not the default but the second one I want to switch to I can't add it to the public variable in the script :

```
public Skybox skybox;
```

I also tried :

```
public Material skybox;
```

This is the skybox settings :

[image: Skybox]

I can't drag it to the script in the inspector. Either if the variable is SkyBox or Material.

What I want to do is to switch with one button between the default skybox and this Sky_0003